# Как сохранить внешний вид кнопки в session storage, чтобы он сохранялся после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, dom

Подскажи, пожалуйста, как сохранить кнопку в session storage, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы она оставалась неизменной.

вот какой кейс:
есть кнопка с надписью КУПИТЬ, которая отрабатывает следующим образом:

1. При нажатии отправляет запрос на сервер
2. Если response.ok кнопке добавляется класс hasBeenPurchased, который меняет background-color и надпись на В КОРЗИНЕ.

Надо:

1. сохранить кнопку с надписью "В КОРЗИНЕ" в session storage
2. получить эту кнопку с надписью "В КОРЗИНЕ" после перезагрузки страницы

Comment: а сама корзина где хранится?

Comment: надо хранить не "внешний вид", а список товаров в корзине, т. к. пользователь гуляет туда-сюда

Comment: Без корзины. Это часть тестового задания.

Comment: кнопка определена для товара, я бы в storage записал список товаров, а при отрисовке списка проверял наличие его в "корзине" и  применял соответствующие стили к кнопке

Comment: Без корзины -- ерунда выходит, если на сайте больше одного товара

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
function getCartKey(){
    return "cart"
}
function getCartItems(){
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(getCartKey())||'[]')
}

function addCurrentProduct(){
    const items = [...getCartItems(),getCurrentProduct()]
    sessionStorage.setItem(getCartKey(),JSON.serialize(items))
    render()
}
function render(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("cart").forEach(el=>{
        el.className = getCurrentProduct() in getCartItems() ? "В КОРЗИНЕ":"КУПИТЬ"
    })
}
function getCurrentProduct(){
    return document.location
}
...
render() // on load
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо. Попробую!